# Looking for a way to do communication between cocoa and amfphp

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a apache/mysql server with amfphp for communication.
Currently, I have an Adobe Air application which uses RemoteObject to communicate with amfphp.
I am looking for a class or something else to communicate between cocoa and php.

Is there a way ?

Thank you for answers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Cocoa AMF to facilitate this type of interaction.  I have used it on several projects with good results overall:

https://github.com/nesium/cocoa-amf